# Chi-squared test and logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, chi-squared-test, contingency-tables

Is there a relation between chi-squared test and logistic regression model in a similar manner between ANOVA and linear regression?

Comment: @Jeremy can you show a small example?  I wouldn't expect it to be actually true (except approximately) and I can't seem to generate an example that shows it. I'd have expected that maybe it could happen with the G-test rather than the ordinary chi-square.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the setting is a $r\times 2$ contingency table, crossclassifying a binary variable with an (unordered) factor with $r$ levels, you can use binary logistic regression or a chi-squared test, and you will get very similar answers.

The logistic regression will give the likelihood-ratio test, and the Pearson Chi-square is the corresponding score test. Details:  [G-test vs Pearson's chi-squared test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/169142/g-test-vs-pearsons-chi-squared-test).  For an $r\times c$ contingency table (both factors unordered) much the same will be true replacing multinomial logistic regression.  So logistic regression can be a good starting point if you need some extensions/generalizations to these chi-squared tests.