# Difference between logistic regression and chi-square for analysis with no covariates?

Tags: logistic, chi-squared-test, count-data

I have a binary response variable (0s and 1s), the distribution of which that I want to compare to chance. I understand I could use logistic regression or a chi-square test to do this and that these should be equivalent but my results are slightly different when I use one versus the other and I'm wondering why.

Specifically, there are 44 1s and 14 0s and the expected distribution would be chance (30 1s, 30 0s). When I run a logistic regression with this code:

```
model<-glm(df$var ~ 1, family=binomial("logit"))
```

I get a z value of 3.465, which converts to a Wald statistic of 12, and p = .00053.

When I run a chi-square test I get X-squared = 13.067, df = 1, p-value = 0.0003006.

Can someone explain to me where exactly these tests differ such that they yield different results?

Comment: A similar post:   https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115835/chi-squared-test-and-logistic-regression/517511#517511

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Pearson $\chi^2$ test, the Wald test, (the likelihood ratio test, Rao's score test, ...) are all approximate. If you have an infinite sample, then they will be exactly the same, but in smaller samples you will find differences.

Comment: Thanks. In that case, is there any reason to prefer one over the other here?

Comment: The Pearson $\chi^2$ test tends to perform badly when your expected counts are small.